# Should I put the name of my manager of the consulting company or the company that I am working with as current employer?

Tags: job-search, applications

I am employed by a consulting company and working as a consutant developer for X company.

I am applying for a job where I should put the name of my current employer. The problem is that, my consulting company isn't well informed about my work and I really don't want to tell them that I leaving. I don't like them and I am not well paid.  I planning my next move quietly till i get accepted of course. Hope it's not mean. Whereas the manager of the X company knows me very well. He always speaks highly of me.

In the job application there is the possibility to forbid the company that i am applying to contact my current employer. I can use it but I would love them to contact my manager at X company.

I was thinking of 3 things:

- Is it possible to put the name of my consulting company as current employer and use the name of the manager at X company in case they want to contact him?
- Is it possible to put the name of current employer X and use the name of the manager at X company in case they want to contact him?
- Is it possible to put the name of both consulting and X company and give both their names? name of my manager at the consulting company and name of manager at X company?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am applying for a job where I should put the name of my current
>   employer.

Since you are employed by the contracting company, that is the name you must use.

If you are asked for referrals, you can use anyone you prefer, including the manager of company X where you are deployed. Make sure you ask permission of this manager before you use their name as a reference.

Comment: If possible, might want to put a "talk with me first" on the part of the form that says not to talk with the current employer.

Comment: If I put don't contact current employer. Do you think they might take it in a wrong way?

Comment: ok. Thank you @JoeStrazzere. It's the right thing to do. thank you so much

Comment: I added the name of my manager in the References part. I didn't apply yet. i'll ask him tomorrow if they can contact him. Thanks again @JoeStrazzere

Answer (score 1):

I'd put both companies on the application. You don't want either of them to be contacted yet, and that's perfectly normal.

They're presumably giving you the option, because if you were already working out your notice on the current job you might not mind. Even so, give them a heads up first that someone may be giving them a call.

If and when the time comes to take references, it's again perfectly normal not to be putting your current boss down. A co-worker or an important customer - in your case your boss at Company X - will more than suffice. Again, give him a heads up first, and with a bit of luck you'll be in a position to tell your other boss that you're going at the same time as handing your notice in.

That's the ideal way to do it anyway, although don't be too surprised if people talk and you've got to deal with some workplace awkwardness as a result.